# linux file tree database file

Tags: linux, locate

When 
i install mlocate i must run updatedb
I was wondering if there is a db file with all the files on the system and their paths

is there a msterfile that contains all the file location/names on the linux system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

From `man updatedb` :

> FILES
>
> ```
>   /etc/updatedb.conf
>          A configuration file.  See updatedb.conf(5).
>
>   /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
>           The database updated by default.
> ```

Comment: And If i dont have mlocate
Is there any msterdb file by default on linux

Comment: No. That db file is created the first `updatedb` runs.